# SQL - Joining multiple tables with shared index

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table

I have three data tables that different columns (<500 each) but share a common "id" column.

They look like:

table A

```
   id    A1    A2   ...      
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ...
```

table B

```
   id1    B1    B2   ...  
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ...
```

table C

```
   id2    C1    C2   ...  
   1    xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ...
```

My goal is to join them into something like:

```
   id    A1    A2   ...   B1    B2   ...   C1    C2   ...  
   1    xxx   xxx   ...  xxx   xxx   ...  xxx   xxx   ...
   2    xxx   xxx   ...  xxx   xxx   ...  xxx   xxx   ...
  ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...
```

I was trying to join them together using

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_C
ON table_A.id = table_C.id2;
```

and it's been taking hours. But joining two of them takes less than 5 minutes using:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id1
```

I tried using `EXPLAIN`, and here's what I get:

```
   id  select_type    table    type  posibble_keys    key    key_len    ref      rows  filtered   Extra
   1    SIMPLE       table_A    ALL     (Null)      (Null)    (Null)   (Null)   59670   100       
   1    SIMPLE       table_B    ALL     (Null)      (Null)    (Null)   (Null)   39776   100    Using; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) where
   1    SIMPLE       table_C    ALL     (Null)      (Null)    (Null)   (Null)   50208   100    Using; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) where
```

I searched around and found posts saying that "Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" is a low-efficiency way and suggesting disabling this using `SET optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';`. However, when I tried this, even joining two tables take more than 10 minutes, which seems a huge drop on perfoemance.

It seems that BNL is used only when there is no index to join on, which is not true given that all three tables have the "id" column?

I really wonder if there is some way to make the joining of these tables faster.

1. Maybe I should adjust the way of joining in my code?
2. Maybe I should turn some option on/off?
3. Any advice?

Comment: Are you need to get all columns for your tables? otherwise you don't need to use `select *`

Comment: @D-Shih yes unfortunately I really do need all of them :(

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that smaller join works much faster, try to do in these smaller steps.

Start with something like

```sql
CREATE temporary TABLE my_table_AB
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B
ON table_A.id = table_B.id
```

then

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT *
FROM my_table_AB
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_C
ON my_table_AB.id = table_C.id
```

Another thing is - do you need to have `LEFT JOIN` here?

---

As it was marked as solved and we found solution during discussion, I will put it here just for reference - an issue there was missing primary keys. After adding it, it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks Adam! When done in smaller steps, the first part is fast ~5 mins, but as far as I tried, second part still takes very long (1 hr + and I terminated the query).

Comment: I think I need to ```LEFT JOIN```? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I could've expected that you tried that :) Are these times the same when you do that in different order? For example, join tables A with C, then with B, or start with C and B, then A?

Comment: And `LEFT JOIN` is needed only if you would have some rows in table A which have no matching rows in table B. If this is not a case, you should use `INNER JOIN` then.

Comment: Good question! Let me give it a try

Comment: Oh then I really do need ```LEFT JOIN``` since table A is like a table of contents...

Comment: What is amount of rows (let's start with table A) for which it took hours? Did you try to run that for smaller amount of rows? One thing is to know whether your system can handle that (to have up to 1500 columns per table), and another is that maybe it could be done when you' insert data in batches.

Comment: table A has 50000+ rows. I think my system can handle it. There should be <1000 columns in total. Could you please elaborate on insertin data in batches? (Im really new to SQL

Comment: Please check @Gordon Linoff's suggestion to verify whether you don't have multiply id rows in tables B and C for the same id from table A which may be root of the issue for you.
By inserting data in batches I would consider to split that down in steps like: create new table without any data then insert from all tables but with some condition (by `table_A.id` most likely) which would take only 1000 or 10000 rows, then repeat this step with another set of 1k or 10k rows, repeat in some loop until you finish all rows. This should be achievable within sql procedure or with some external language.

Comment: On the other hand - maybe you could just use plain old view for that? What is business use for this?

Comment: Thanks! I check and the result is 59838. Also each id occurs at most once in each table.

Comment: these are just some financial data about some firms in some years. each row is [company x year] e.g. Goolge at 2019. The columns are stuff like revenue, profit, costs etc.

Comment: I join them three with condition ```WHERE id = 1``` to make a new table where we have all the columns and only 1 row.

Comment: I tried something like
```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT *
FROM table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B ON table_A.id = table_B.id1
LEFT JOIN table_C ON table_A.id = table_C.id2
WHERE table_A.id < 1000;
```
and this is still taking super long

Comment: even when I try ```WHERE `table_A.id = 2``` to insert one row, it takes 1.34 seconds...no wonder it takes so long for 50000+ rows

Comment: Do you have properly created primary and foreign keys on these tables? If it takes so long for even one value it suggests that it may be doing some table scans instead of using indexes.

Comment: Thanks so much @Adam Tokarski! After adding primary keys, it is done within a minute

Comment: @GrumpyCivet - and I'll bet that your _original_ single, 3-table, query is faster than using a temp table?

Answer (score 1):

it may be choking since you are trying to create table from the select.  The issue is that a new table can not have a duplicate of a column name in a table.  You may need to be explicit, something like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
SELECT
      a.id,
      a.A1,
      a.A2,
      a.[rest of columns],
      b.B1,
      b.B2,
      b.[rest of columns],
      c.C1,
      c.C2,
      c.[rest of columns]
   FROM 
      table_A a
         LEFT JOIN table_B b
            ON a.id = a.id
         LEFT JOIN table_C c
            ON a.id = c.id
```

With 500 rows it should be almost instantaneous

Comment: thanks @DRapp! I'm sure that column names are all distinct. There are 1000 different columns so I'm afraid I have to use ```SELECT *``` instead of typing them all out. Also there are 50000+ rows not 500 unfortunately

Comment: @GrumpyCivet, the DUPLICATE columns are the "ID" on tables B and C.  You had A.id, B.id, c.id which would make it choke.  Additionally, having 1000s of different columns smells of bad table structure definition

Comment: Oh I actaully have them like id in table A, id1 in table B, and id2 in table C... - my bad! should have made it clear in the question.

Comment: @GrumpyCivet, then that said, the select * should have been quick, but if it has 1000's of columns per table, that just really smells bad design and should be a consideration of refactoring.  That is probably what is choking the crap out of the engine!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably generating a Cartesian product between the three tables.  You can calculate the total number of rows in the result set using:

```
select sum(a.cnt * coalesce(b.cnt, 1) * coalesce(c.cnt, 1))
from (select id, count(*) as cnt from a group by id) a left join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt from b group by id) b
     on a.id = b.id left join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt from c group by id) c
     on a.id = c.id;
```

My guess is that the number is much, much larger than you expect.  This is because `b` and `c` both have multiple rows for some `id`s.  You haven't explained what results you want in such cases, so it is hard to provide an actual solution to your question.  But this should explain the performance issue.

Comment: thanks! though I am 100% sure each id occurs only once in each table e.g. there can't be two id "1" in any table.

Comment: it has 59838. btw I think you have any extra right parenthesis on your line 5

Comment: @GrumpyCivet . . . That is not so large.  The query shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 0):

As we need all the columns from all the 3 tables based on joining on id column of all tables, Instead of Left Join can't we use INNER JOIN here?

Comment: table A is like a table of contects - I need all rows from table A in there :(

Comment: CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
 -- All columns definition goes here
 -- Make Id as an indexed columns
 id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
(
 -- List all required columns here
)
SELECT -- list all required columns here
FROM table_A
LEFT  JOIN table_B
ON   table_A.id = table_B.id

SELECT  *
FROM  #TempTable A
LEFT  JOIN table_C
ON   A.id = table_C.id;